# Generate Android App Bundle aab from apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

I'm using Xamarin to develop android app. As I know, it [hasn't supported android app bundle](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1709). So I would like to know if there is any way to generate an Android App Bundle - aab file from the apk via terminal? Or any other good way to process ?

Comment: the `bundletool` does not create bundles out of the nothing; it only works the other way around.

Answer (score 8):

No, the APK itself doesn't have enough information for the bundletool to create a bundle (AAB). It can work the other way round - to create an APK from a bundle.

If you want to create a bundle by hand, you will need to do a lot of stuff by hand, including resource handling, code compilation etc. You can find more information about how to do that in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build).

Comment: Thank @Izabela for the information.

I'm following the steps introduce on the above link with sample android project. The step to have compiled resources is ok, but it's failed on link step with aapt2.
`error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` not found. I thought it's depending to something like `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` but I don't know how to add them to aapt2 link parameters.

Did you have this problem before? Any comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to take out the resources from the libraries you depend on, merge them, compile them (same as your local resources) and then link them all, otherwise link will fail. Honestly, it's just the easiest to build with gradle.

Answer (score -1):

answer [given by Deeep Dip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940210/10180730) is right, but he might not be able to explain it properly (step-by-step). Also the tool "apktoaabconverter.com" he mentioned below was paid (at the time I'm answering the question).

I followed his manual steps and came out with a simplest solution which is using the [telegram platform](https://telegram.org/).

Actually I found some bots there simply by searching for "APK to AAB" in the Global search bar. This bots on their side are using the same procedure @deeep-div was trying to explain (Found out via logs attached with .aab).

Direct links to the telegram bots:

> 1. http://t.me/apktoaabbot (Used to be busy a lot)
> 2. http://t.me/apktoaab_bot (This one I used to convert my .apk to .aab)

**NOTE: You may need wait around 30 minutes after sending your .apk file. Time could vary as per the load on bot servers.**

Comment: How long did it take for you? I just uploaded to both and one is 6th and other submission is in 64th position in the queue

Comment: @YigitAlparslan Sorry to be late dear. Think you got at least one response out of them.

Comment: I got no reply from them over 12hrs now made me think they just want the email to spam junk ;-)) . Probably will dig into actually doing the hard way with the bundle command line tool.  I have bumbleebee A.S. but import doesn't work followed a bunch of posts about it &they don't work 4 me