# Is there an established way to turn an APK into an AAB?

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

I've been searching online the entire day and I can't find a way to do it that doesn't involve online tools, sending your files to bots on messaging apps, that hasn't "expired" (old github repos), isn't some very vague instructions or isn't about re-writing the app with Android Studio.

Right now, I have a mobile app coded in Python with Kivy. It's a very simple 20 lines app, just for testing purposes. I can successfully turn it into an APK with Buildozer and use it on my phone, however I can't upload it on Google Play because they no longer accept APK's, only AAB's.

So here I am with an APK file (and my source .py file). What is it that I need to do in order to turn either of those into an AAB file?

Comment: It seems that [Buildozer support for AAB is in progress](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/pull/1356) and there are [instructions for using a development build now](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#release-builds).

Comment: The main README on their repo says AAB is supported now, but there doesn't seem to be a proper section in the documentation for it. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149494/how-to-build-an-aab-using-buildozer-via-docker) might help

Comment: duplicate: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845539/generate-android-app-bundle-aab-from-apk-file

Comment: buildozer 1.3.0 worked for me with no particular documentation even needed, just add the ```android.release_artifact = aab``` to the spec file. The signing instructions are straightforward and can be found from several of the links in above comments.